# How to deploy multiple projects in Dokku with Docker simultaneously

Tags: docker, devops, dokku, dokku-alt

I want to deploy multiple projects simultaneously in Dokku using Docker. I'm aware of individual deployment using `dokku git:from-image APP_NAME ImageName`. However, I'm looking for a method to deploy multiple projects at once to avoid the possibility of one project updating before another.